# Java class in an Android Library or Parcelable object in a Java Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my project I have a set of java objects as part of the model of my application, they are all in a Java Library module as they are pure Java.
The Android app module use them and that's not a problem, I also need to pass these through my activities, so making them `Parcelable` is the way to go.

But I have some trouble in Android Studio doing so because `Parcelable` is something from Android and I haven't succeed in using it in the Java module. So I have tested to move my classes in an Android Library, but Android seems to ignore them since they are pure Java, there is an icon with a red J on each one of them. To verify my supposition, I have tested to create a Java class in the Android module, but there is no option to do it.

Is there a way to keep the classes in a separated module, and if so, what is it? Or should I move all the classes in the app module?
(I would prefer to avoid the last solution if possible)

Thank you

**Edit:** The solution seems to be using an Android library, but I don't know why Android Studio behaves badly with my module, I can't create java class and java packages in the main package of the library:

[image: Can't create a Java class in pact44.objects]

Also, I can't create packages in `pact44` main package:

[image: Can't create packages in pact44.objects]

Comment: If performance is not an issue: have you thought of using java-Serializable instead of Android-Parcelable? for details see http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: Yes it does, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

> So I have tested to move my classes in an Android Library, but Android seems to ignore them since they are pure Java.

Ignore them? What do you mean? You created a library module, moved your code into it and then you cannot access this classes from your app module?

> To verify my supposition, I have tested to create a Java class in the Android module, but there is no option to do it.

And how do you create activities classes for example? There must be the option for creating a new Java class. If the IDE doesn't give you the option to create a new Java class means that you are trying to create it in a place where you're not supposed to do that.

If you want to separate your library code from the app code but you still want to have access to Android classes in your library the best way is to create a new "android library module". Remember to add the library as dependency in the app build.gradle

Look here : https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: It's already in the post, I have tried it but android studio doesn't propose me to create a class in it...
In fact that is the real problem, I've just seen that I have another android library in which I can create Java classes. I don't know why Android Studio don't propose it to me in the new module...

Comment: Are gradle syncing the project after you created the new library? Are you trying to create your Java class in src/main/java ? If you try to create a java class outside this directory, the ide will not give you this option.

Comment: _So I have tested to move my classes in an Android Library, but Android seems to ignore them since they are pure Java._: This is not true in fact, sorry about that. I post two images showing the problem.
@Flood2d I have synced the project and it doesn't change anything, thank you though